# Update Listview from Sms BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a listview in writeMessage activity.When user writes message it will show what it writes but when a message receive it do not.I have to back and again start activity.I tried to register broadcast to my activity but i cant.

i define this top of my activity :

```
public class CMesWriteMessage extends Activity {
     private BroadcastReceiver the_receiver = new IncomingSms(){

         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
             addItems();

         }
     };
     private IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED);

...
...
```

}

And register it like that:

```
protected void onResume() {

    // Register reciever if activity is in front
    this.registerReceiver(the_receiver, filter);
    super.onResume();
}

protected void onPause() {

     // Unregister reciever if activity is not in front
     this.unregisterReceiver(the_receiver);
     super.onPause();
}
```

Where am i wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i change my action and everthing is fine now.Here is the correct code:

```
private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
private IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION);
```

EDİT:

I make my main operation in my broadcast class.In this activity, i only update listview. So to reach this achive i edit my code like this :

```
private BroadcastReceiver the_receiver = new IncomingSms(){

         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
             super.onReceive(c, i);
             //My activity special operations.

         }
};
```

NOTE : IncomingSms is my main broadcastreceiver class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the entire problem, but super.onPause()/super.onResume() should be the first calls in their respective overrides:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    this.registerReceiver(the_receiver, filter);
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    this.unregisterReceiver(the_receiver);
}
```

Comment: I fixed it but nothing changed.